# How to fill a web form using Java (Don't want to submit it, but just want to fill up the fields from database)

Tags: java

There is a requirement to fill a webform of some particular site of which HTML source I have available. I want to fill the fields on this form from the database records. I don't want to POST the request to the server as the application user would first verify the filled data and will submit the form manually.

Is there any way in java through which I can achieve this? I have already achieved this in VB .Net but want to include as a part of bigger application which is already developed in java and implements a business logic.

You help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
SRA

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far and explain the difficulties you encountered with it.

Comment: I have not tried any code so far. I am not even getting any starting point. Reading about Selenium but still any other way out will be helpful.

Comment: This question doesn't give enough context.  Where is this Java suppoed to run?  In the user's web browser or on the server?

Comment: Java would be running on the server. If we can use user's web browser for filling the form then it would be great. But if we cannot using java, then what can be the solution?

Comment: Do you have control on page generation (You generate page with your code on your server)? Or you should fill some page from server you don't control (you control only client browser)?

Answer (score 0):

> Java would be running on the server.

In that case, you just modify the server so that it generates the HTML with the `<input>` elements prefilled with the values from the database; e.g. using the `value` attributes.  It is a little bit more complicated for selectors, where you have to make sure that one of the choices is preselected.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood your context. I want to fill the web form on behalf of the client and not from the server directly. Sorry once again. Can you guide me with appropriate solution again. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to access DB and you also need to fill web form from the client side. If you use Selenium it will be this scenario:
User starts your program. Program opens browser window, logs in and fills form. User checks data and presses "send"-button. Browser window automatically closed by program (potentially possible to keep browser window open, but it's better to clean resources and finish program).

Code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

    try {
        processPage();
    } finally {
        webDriver.quit();
    }
}

private static void processPage() throws InterruptedException {
    webDriver.get("http://some_page_url");

    // Page element search example
    List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(XPATH_STR));

    // Fill page here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Vadim... I will give it a hit and let you know. Will also explore other powers of Selenium. :) Thanks once again.